# Past simple or present perfect?

Tags: grammar, tenses, present-perfect, simple-past

Is it better to say "I learned" or "I have learned English from a very young age"?

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

**I learned English as a child.** which means that I finished my studies of language when I was a child

or

**I have been learning English since I was a child.** which means that I am still learning English, but I started when I was a child.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have learned a lot from your answer. Is it customary to use present perfect after the preposition "from"? Another example would be : "I have studied English along with French from a very young age." Since learning is an ongoing process (in my case, anyhow), isn't the past simple a bit too finite?